Linkedin API url used in post being broken?
I'm working on the implementation using LinkedIn API, everything seems to be working however I noticed a weird interaction with urls that I add to the content of the post.
When I create post and try to post it with API, I got 0 errors, 201 come back saying that Post was created
I can see it on the page, however sometimes LinkedIn removes the underscore(s) from URL and sometimes it doesn't
url example:
https://yourapp.com/your_page

My question is should underscore also be encoded like urns, I can't find any info about it on doc.
I expect the api to constantly work with the url's containing underscores.
